# How to hide the contents of an image

Tags: android

In the activity I had an image, but I want to hide its contents until the click.

When one arrives at the activity

[image: activity]

When clicking on this image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**set default image** in your activity imageView: [add this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyMi1.png)

and then **set onClickListener on your imageview.**

**inside onClickListner** add image in imageview like this: [add this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMw0l.png)

**imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);** OR

**imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);**

thats it.